# Prestashop - out of stock list

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, blocklayered

I have a prestashop shop, when I sell t-shirts. Every t-shirt have several sizes (combinations), i.e. M, L, XL etc.

In `blocklayered` filter there are two filters: "Available" and "Out of stock" products, but they behave weirdly: "out of stock" filter shows products, that have 0 quantity in one/several sizes.

How can I modify this to show on "out of stock" list only products, that have no items available in **ALL** available sizes.

What I mean is when a t-shirt have 3 items in size M, but 0 in size L, I do not want it to show on "Out of stock" list.

The second thing is - how can I hide products, that are truly "out of stock" (no items in all combinations) from default category list page? What I want to achieve is that on category pages we have "Archive" tab, which should show products that used to be available in shop, but they are not anymore.

I use PS 1.6.1.9

Answer (score 0):

Open www/themes/yourtheme/product-list (Dont forget to backup)

Search for

```
{assign var='nbLi' value=$products|@count}
```

Right below add

```
{foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
    {if ($product.quantity <= 0)}
        {$nbLi=$nbLi-1}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Search for

```
{foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
```

Right below add

```
{if ($product.quantity > 0)}
```

Search for

```
{/foreach}
```

Right above add

```
{/if}
```

Replace all instances of

```
  $smarty.foreach.products.total
```

and

```
$smarty.foreach.products.iteration
```

with

```
$nbLi
```

This question was anwsered by MEG Venture in the prestashop forum.
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/537182-disable-out-of-stock-product-from-listing-only/

Comment: Thanks, but more important for me is this "Archive" page, what means displaying products that are trully out of stock

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in StockAvailable.php core class of PrestaShop that can be used to find the actual quantity of any option of a product.

```
StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct()
```

You can simply run through a loop for every option of a product and find the quantity for all options and mark the product out of stock only if any option is not available.